# How to prevent Flask redirecting to the default port of 5000?

Tags: python, flask, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to run a [Python sample for using Microsoft Graph](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-send-mail/issues/3). It uses Flask libraries for a mini-application that can be run using the Flask's standalone web server.

I've modified the application initialization line as

```
APP.run(port=9999)
```

And it starts running successfully at `http://localhost:9999/`, but then after a step, it redirects to `http://localhost:5000` which is problematic.

If I change the initial part of the URL in my browser to `http://localhost:9999` and hit ENTER, it continues to function as expected.

How can tell Flask to "redirect to the URL with the port number I declared in APP.run"?

Comment: thats weird. Can you show the initialization of the APP object? Also how are you running it?

Comment: Everything is done in this single file: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-send-mail/blob/master/sample.py

Comment: After authentication where does the redirect callback return on the flask app? Did you configure graph to redirect on success to `localhost:5000/login/authorized` instead of `:9999/login/authorized`?

Comment: So, this should be configured on Microsoft Graph side? Not only a Pyhton code configuration issue you mean?

Comment: You need to configure the `REDIRECT_URI` on python side and on the Microsoft Graph settings for your application

Comment: Indeed! One more thing learned about Microsoft Graph API :) Thanks!

Comment: What's that with 3 Close Votes? This is certainly about programming. I'm referring to some Python code, and the answers include a change to that Python code, together with other changes in the comments. Why this is marked as off-topic, is a mystery to me! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `config.py` file, you have a route there with 5000 port

Comment: Changed that to 9999 and then I got from Microsoft side: "Sign in

Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
AADSTS50011: The reply address 'http://localhost:9999/login/authorized' does not match the reply addresses configured for the application: '9eea536f-ccdf-4472-94d8-7ca6acfea142'. More details: not specified"

Comment: You should configure your Microsoft Graph app to allow new redirect URL

Comment: OK, I had to go to https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/application/ and change Redirect URLs to http://localhost:9999/login/authorized . I'll accept your answer.